# Why can I see an AD container from ADExplorer and not from other browsers?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Ok, so I need a really Active Directory expert for this one.

I am encoutering a problem where  I view different things from different LDAP Browsers.

I want to view the deleted objects container. 
When I access Active Directory through ADExplorer I can see this container. When I access the same Active Directory, with the same user from JXplorer I cannot see the deleted objects container.
Also from Softera LDAP Browser happens the same as JXPlorer

Do you have any idea why this is happening?
Do you have maybe any other LDAP Browser you can reccomend?
Thanks

Comment: ldp.exe is a DC integrated tool that allows you to view the contents of the Deleted Objects container: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978013.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The ability to enumerate the deleted objects container in Active Directory will depend on the software in use (as you found out). To be able to view the deleted objects container (and any deleted objects in general), the software needs to use the LDAP control called `LDAP_SERVER_SHOW_DELETED_OID`. From the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366989(v=vs.85).aspx):

> LDAP_SERVER_SHOW_DELETED_OID control code
>
> The LDAP_SERVER_SHOW_DELETED_OID control is used with an extended LDAP
>   search function to specify that the search results include any deleted
>   objects that match the search filter.

Unless the software lets you use a custom LDAP control when connecting to AD (or has builtin support for viewing deleted objects in AD), then it wont be able to see them at all.

Comment: Is there a way to activate or to find this control in the software??

Comment: I took a quick look at the docs for it before I wrote this, and no...not that I could tell. I'm not familiar with this software though, you'd probably have to submit a feature request to get this functionality added.